# Swagger not working properly with SB 3 + SpringDoc 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I have been developing new APIs in Springboot 3 and it has been more a headache than something good, but finally I'm able to do something. Issue is that I was able to add Swagger to it, with OpenAPI from Spring-doc release 2. but the configuration file is not reading my properties. Also I have troubles trying to set up my bearer authentication....

This is my actual swagger: [Swagger + spring-doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VOmg.png)

And third issue related to this is... I keep can't make the swagger to read the default responses... even I configured like in the old versions, but I couldn't make it work...

1. For properties, I have tried to add them before the config class, and ad a Bean in methods.
2. For bearer, I was following Baeldung JWT Swagger guide, but It confuses me a little, tried to run but didnt work.

This is my OpenApiConfig class (commented lines are because they are not compatible with tag declaration):

```
package info.peluka.csaread.config;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Contact;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.License;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.servers.Server;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;

@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info =@Info(
                title = "${module-name}",
                version = "${api-version}",
                contact = @Contact(
                        name = "Joseph", email = "CSA_Read_API@peluka.info", url = "https://www.peluka.info"
                ),
                license = @License(
                        name = "Apache 2.0", url = "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
                ),
                description = "${module-description}"
        ),
        servers = @Server(
                url = "${api.server.url}",
                description = "Production"
        )
)
public class OpenApiConfig {

    private final String moduleName;
    private final String apiVersion;

    private final String moduleDescription;

    public OpenApiConfig(
            @Value("${module-name}") String moduleName,
            @Value("${api-version}") String apiVersion,
            @Value("${module-description}") String moduleDescription) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
        this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
        this.moduleDescription = moduleDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Configure the OpenAPI components.
     *
     * @return Returns fully configure OpenAPI object
     * @see OpenAPI
     */
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customizeOpenAPI() {
        //@formatter:off
        final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                        .addList(securitySchemeName))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName, new SecurityScheme()
                                .name(securitySchemeName)
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                .scheme("bearer")
                                .description(
                                        "Provide the JWT token. JWT token can be obtained from the /token endpoint. If need to create an user, contact Griffith.")
                                .bearerFormat("JWT")));
        //@formatter:on

    }

//    @Bean
//    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application-description}")
//                                 String appDesciption,
//                                 @Value("${application-version}")
//                                 String appVersion) {
//        return new OpenAPI()
//                .info(new Info()
//                        .title("CSA Read API - Swagger")
//                        .version(appVersion)
//                        .description(appDesciption)
//                        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
//                        .license(new License().
//                                name("Apache 2.0").
//                                url("http://springdoc.org")));
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
//        final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
//        return new OpenAPI()
//                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
//                .components(
//                        new Components()
//                                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
//                                        new SecurityScheme()
//                                                .name(securitySchemeName)
//                                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
//                                                .scheme("bearer")
//                                                .bearerFormat("JWT")
//                                )
//                )
//                .info(new Info().title(moduleName).version(apiVersion).description(moduleDescription));
//    }
}
```

3. Inside my controller, I have this (It's just a code block of two endpoints) :

```
(...)
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
(...)

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/csa/api")
@Tag(name = "Users & Clan Controller", description = "This Endpoint manages Users and CSA Members")
public class ClanController extends Helper {

(...)


@PostMapping("/token")
@Operation(summary = "Request a token", description = "Return a new token" )
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = TOKEN_GENERATED_SUCCESSFULLY, content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, content = @Content) })
public ResponseEntity<Object> token(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    try {
        if(!isValidEmail(email))
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, EMPTY);
        var optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        if (!optionalUsers.isPresent())
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, EMPTY);
        var token = getJWTToken(email);
        optionalUsers.get().setToken(token);
        optionalUsers.get().setLastLogin(LocalDate.now());
        usersRepository.save(optionalUsers.get());
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(TOKEN_GENERATED_SUCCESSFULLY, HttpStatus.OK, new Token(token));
    } catch (Exception e){
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostMapping("/updatePW")
@Operation(summary = "Update user password", description = "Return successful if all validations were OK." )
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = PASSWORD_CHANGED_SUCCESSFULLY, content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "406", description = NEW_PASSWORD_ERROR, content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, content = @Content) })
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Bearer Authentication")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updatePassword(@RequestBody OldUser oldUser){
    Users userSaved;
    try {
        if(!isValidEmail(oldUser.getEmail()))
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, oldUser);
        if(!oldUser.getNewPassword().isEmpty() && !isValidPassword(oldUser))
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(NEW_PASSWORD_ERROR, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, oldUser);
        var init = usersRepository.findAll();
        var user = usersRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(oldUser.getEmail(), oldUser.getOldPassword());
        if(!user.isPresent())
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_WRONG, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, oldUser);
        user.get().setPassword(oldUser.getNewPassword());
        if(!oldUser.getNewPassword().isEmpty()){
            userSaved = usersRepository.save(user.get());
        } else {
            userSaved = usersRepository.save(new Users(user.get()));
        }
        emailService.sendMail(userSaved, EMAIL_CHANGE_PASSWORD);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(PASSWORD_CHANGED_SUCCESSFULLY, HttpStatus.CREATED, userSaved);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first image.... For some reasons my "tags" of spring-doc are not working. I have no descriptions, error responses, any definition at all.

I'm working with SpringBoot 3.0.0 and spring-doc version 2.0.0, I have in my pom the following related imported artifacts to spring-doc: springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui, springdoc-openapi-starter-common, springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui

I'm using also Java 17, and recently I started to use Dockerfile (This is the only way I have to make Swagger works without asking me credentials)

Please, any help with this will be very useful. I have been trying to figure out what to do for several weeks now, and the final users need Swagger implemented for easier access....

PS1: The response of api has this format:

```
    {
        "data": {
            "name": "TEST NAME",
            "email": "TEST.EMAIL@EMAIL.io",
            "password": "TEST_PASSWORD",
            "dateCreated": "2022-12-13",
            "dateModified": "2022-12-13",
            "lastLogin": "2022-12-13",
            "token": "Bearer TOKEN",
            "active": true
        },
        "message": "User Created Successfully",
        "status": 201 
}
```

Basically is:

```
{
    "data" : Object
    "message" : String
    "status" : Int
}
```

Where data is the object created in most of cases. Message, just a typo message. status, HTTP Code with the status of operation...

Answer (score 0):

Any success? I have similar issues. The `@RestController`-s are auto scanned and the methods/endpoints are displayed, but `@Tag` names and `@Operation` summaries are missing from the ui and the `/v3/api-docs` response. If I add tags to the operation that works (eg. `@Operation(summary = "test", tags = { "test" })`), but that is not a desired solution.

Regarding the other issues normally you don't need any properties. The default values are fine.

For the auth part you can use something like this for oauth2:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    private String authServer;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String realm;

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI api() {
        var securitySchemeName = "oauth2";
        var authUrl = String.format("%s/realms/%s/protocol/openid-connect", this.authServer, this.realm);
        var tokenUrl = authUrl + "/token";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Service API")
                        .description("Service application")
                        .version("v0.0.1"))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName, new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme()
                                .type(io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2)
                                .description("Oauth2 flow")
                                .flows(new OAuthFlows()
                                        .authorizationCode(new OAuthFlow()
                                                .authorizationUrl(authUrl + "/auth")
                                                .refreshUrl(tokenUrl)
                                                .tokenUrl(tokenUrl)
                                                .scopes(new Scopes())
                                        ))
                        ))
                .security(List.of(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName)));
    }
```

Or this for JWT:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

  @Bean
  public OpenAPI api() {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    return new OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
        .components(
            new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                    new SecurityScheme()
                        .name(securitySchemeName)
                        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                        .scheme("bearer")
                        .bearerFormat("JWT")
                )
        )
        .info(new Info().title("Service API").description("Service").version("v0.0.1"));
  }
}
```